# Need a Freeware APC software

Tags: backup

I have a **SmartUps 750**

I have it hooked up with the drivers installed works great but would like to be able to see visual stats via pc.

I have the USB cable connected.

I've read that *APC Powerchute Personal Edition* would be good but cant seem to download it off their site **is there any other alternatives** I could use. Im using it as a power-backup for my Backup Server.

**Or possibly a way to get this download?**

Okay I found an Alternative that works well below.

The alternative is called [BatteryMon](http://www.passmark.com/products/batmon.htm) 
It's does everything that it needs to

- Monitors battery charge
- Tells you detailed stats
- Has email notifications
- let's you monitor as many backup systems as you would like.
- Keeps logs with times and tempratures

If anyone would like to list any other Alternatives I will always be open to them.

Comment: Welcome to SR! We don't give advice here on "how/where to download X", but recommend software for specific requirements. So we might be able to help you if you [edit] your question and list yours. For guidance, please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)

Comment: Thank you I will edit it I actually did some more Research and may delete my Question as I have found and Alternative that does exactly what I want.

Comment: Instead of simply deleting your question, you might consider [edit]ing it accordingly and [post your solution as answer](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). It might help others in similar situations :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't indicated the OS you want to monitor the UPS with, but explore both NUT and apcupsd in linux and bsd.

1. NUT may be found at http://networkupstools.org/ and I see there's now a windows build too.
2. apcupsd is found at http://www.apcupsd.org/ and there is an OSX and Windows build.
3. to use the UPS support built into windows.  Its not stunning but simple signalling like "ON-BATT" and "LOW-BATT" should make the OS do the right thing.  Its been in windows since NT4. and probably earlier, although it appears to be deprecated on win7 and later.
4. Another option for you is that bigger UPSs support an SNMP management card, which makes your UPS a network-attached device, and multiple clients may monitor the UPS status using SNMP.   APC's docs say that your SmartUPS 750 does have the slot for this.

May not be possible for other users, because smaller UPS may not have an expansion slot and are limited to serial or USB connectors.

This allows for one decently large UPS to serve many physical clients without needing a separate UPS for each.
The expansion card has product code AP9630 andlooks like this:
[image]

More details at http://www.apc.com/shop/nz/en/products/UPS-Network-Management-Card-2/P-AP9630

Or an AP9631 which has environmental monitoring connectors
[image]

Details on that one are http://www.apc.com/shop/nz/en/products/UPS-Network-Management-Card-2-with-Environmental-Monitoring/P-AP9631

Downside: they're not cheap, and they're hardware not software as per this stack's purpose.  However being able to ping your UPS, or SNMP probe it, is pretty cool.  Maybe you already have this card?  Worth checking.

5. Finally - windows download links as you asked for

   5.1 APC Power Chute Personal for Windows. http://www.apc.com/shop/us/en/products/PowerChute-Personal-Edition-V3-0-2-for-Windows-10-8-7-Vista-XP-Home-Server-Multi-Language-/P-SFPCPE302

   5.2 Latest APC Power Chute Business Edition which is V9.2  http://www.apc.com/shop/us/en/products/PowerChute-Business-Edition-5-Node-v9-2/P-SFPCBE92

Comment: @NetworkKingPin sorry I edited and added more info.